# How can I add a transition between two cuts of the same clip in Premiere Pro CS5?

Tags: video-editor, premiere, cs5

I've run into what I think is a bug in Premiere Pro CS5.  I've got one large clip that was pulled from an analog camera, and I'm cutting it into scenes.  When I try to add a transition between two such scenes, it just doesn't work.  If I do a two second clock wipe, for instance, I can see the hand of the clock rotating, but I just see the left image for one second, then a sudden cut to the right image for one second, with no transition.  Can anyone confirm that this is a bug, and is there a workaround?  Thanks.

Comment: Have you made sure that the two clips are completely next to each other with no blank space in between?

Comment: Yes.  If they're not, you can't add a transition at all.  In my case, I can add it, but it doesn't work.

Comment: You can add a transition, it will only be to black.. I use to edit my videos in Premiere Pro CS5.5, and they are pulled of an analog camera.. It works for me.

Comment: How old and how pricy is our computer?

Comment: Probably fade to black and back would work, but that's kind of annoying.  I want a real transition.  This doesn't seem too much to ask.  The computer is a dual core Intel i5 with 4GB of RAM.  Not huge, not terrible.  Why?

Comment: Ok, I made videos on a terrible computer in Premiere once, and I had strange problems like you have too.. Oh, I mean, if you don't make sure they are lined up correctly they would transition into black and then the next clip will just pop up, because the transition will be at the end of the clip. If you save with transparency you can see that the black is actually transparent..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I never got this to work, but for some reason, Premiere did allow the fade to black transition, so I used that one.  Not ideal, but it sufficed for this project.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your setup correctly, then this is not exactly a bug. Let's say you have two media files A and B. Let the frames constituting media A be A1-A100 and the frames of B be B1-B100. Let's say A is trimmed to A1-A75 on the timeline and right next to it is B trimmed to B26-B100. Now, if you add a 50 frame transition centered at the A-B interface, the editing software will use B1-B25 as the target video counterpart to A51-A75 on the timeline and A76-A100 as the source video counterpart to B26-B50. So when you do a 50 frame dissolve from A to B, B1-B25 will start fading in as A51-A75 starts fading out. In your case, you seem to be transitioning between contiguous scenes, so they are IDENTICAL. So an additive dissolve, for example, will almost flash to double luminance before settling into the new clip. A borderless linear wipe shouldn't register and so forth.